How do you tan a deer hide to make clothes?
How do you tan a deer hide to make clothes

Jeremy, on this site a bit of previous research is expected. A simple internet search will give you many sites which each will give you one or more tanning methods, way to many for an answer here. Once you have done the basic research you can come back and ask detailed questions on parts of the process you still have questions about.

There are a few different methods.
The basic steps are:

fleshing -> removing fat and gristle from the hide
de-hairing -> removing the hair
tanning -> placing the hide in a solution to preserve it.
stretching -> making the now leather pliable

There are different solutions that you can use for tanning.  This link uses vinegar for tanning Another common material for tanning is the brain as in this link (Each deer has enough brain material to tan its own hide).
You may also have local tanneries that would be able to tan the hide for you (this is what I do to save as fleshing is not a fun process)
